# Package won't work with angular production build

Tags: angular, ckeditor, angular-cli, angular-components, ckeditor5

I created a library which wraps the [CKEditor 5](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/index.html) into an Angular Form Control and provided this library as a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor-form-controls) on npmjs.

When I build the Angular application where that package is imported with its module with ng build everything works fine.

If I build the application for production it seems like any dependencies or so are missing because the component I want to use does not work.

After building the library the package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "ckeditor-form-controls",
    "version": "0.0.4",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.0.1",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11"
    },
    "main": "bundles/ckeditor-form-controls.umd.js",
    "module": "fesm5/ckeditor-form-controls.js",
    "es2015": "fesm2015/ckeditor-form-controls.js",
    "esm5": "esm5/ckeditor-form-controls.js",
    "esm2015": "esm2015/ckeditor-form-controls.js",
    "fesm5": "fesm5/ckeditor-form-controls.js",
    "fesm2015": "fesm2015/ckeditor-form-controls.js",
    "typings": "ckeditor-form-controls.d.ts",
    "metadata": "ckeditor-form-controls.metadata.json",
    "sideEffects": false,
    "dependencies": {
        "tslib": "^1.9.0"
    }
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'childCount' of undefined
at main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1
at Yl (main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1)
at Nl (main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1)
at main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1
at br.change (main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1)
at Fl (main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1)
at zl._initPlaceholder (main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1)
at zl.init (main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1)
at main.962748ac39bd9e0b2a2a.js:1
at t.invoke (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at e.run (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at e.runTask (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at g (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at y (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (polyfills.6082c74956d5f30a31fd.js:1)
```

**I opened an issue for that on GitHub: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/issues/68**

Comment: Please show your code of your component and check if there is any error log in console

Comment: Why are you setting it as a PeerDependency instead of a normal Dependency

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc Done!

Comment: @DanielTurcich is it dependecy because the package needs it?

Answer (score 5):

delete `[config]="{ placeholder: 'Description' }"` from your html. I have same problem. when I delete it, it works, but no placeholder. In this case, you cannot use placeholder.

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus It is Angular defect, so makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, below changes worked for me:

in tsconfig.json:

- from "target": "es2015" to "target": "es6"
- removed placeholder.

Note: I'm using my own customized ckEditor build:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gvreddy04/ckeditor5-build-classic-all-features

Comment: Thanks for the package link, I've just spent hours trying to do this. They really should supply a 'kitchen sink' example you can remove stuff from with config.

Comment: for me remove placeholder was enough.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with `ckeditor5-angular` and the production build process. See [this issue here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/issues/68) on their github.

Comment: It was me who created that issue! :)

Comment: Haha! Indeed! Oops! :)